# Blazor WebAssembly App in .NET 5.0 with MatBlazor 2.8.0 - Cannot provide a value for property 'PortalService' on type 'MatBlazor.MatPortalHost'

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, matblazor

I have followed the installation instructions from https://www.matblazor.com/.

1.Add @using MatBlazor in main _Imports.razor

```
@using MatBlazor
```

2.Add script section to index.html (head section)

```
<script src="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.js"></script>
<link href="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

3.Add registration of service to Startup.cs

```
services.AddMatBlazor();
```

4.Add MatPortalHost component to root component (App.razor) for some services like MatDialogService, MatPortalService

```
<MatPortalHost></MatPortalHost>
```

Error when starting:

> crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'PortalService' on type 'MatBlazor.MatPortalHost'. There
> is no registered service of type 'MatBlazor.IMatPortalService'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
> 'PortalService' on type 'MatBlazor.MatPortalHost'. There is no
> registered service of type 'MatBlazor.IMatPortalService'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `3.Add registration of service to Startup.cs` is not the same for Blazor WebAssembly App.

Add `builder.Services.AddMatBlazor();` to `Program.cs` `Main` method in the `BlazorWebAssemblyApp.Client` and then everything should work. No need to edit anything in `BlazorWebAssemblyApp.Server` or `BlazorWebAssemblyApp.Shared`.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed as well for my Blazor WASM app!